# GPS tracking system over Radio waves (Ham Radios)?

Tags: gps, tracking, radio-transmission

As I searched in forums I learned that for tacking gps I must send coordinates ovew internet connection or SMS .But as I know we can cominicate via radio waves sending voice ,pics,data .And can I use this for getting data from gps device?Because Ham radio is free.

Answer (score 4):

There are radio bands considered "unlicensed" that are free to use if your transmitter falls within regulated limits.  These are mainly "line-of-sight" bands.  Common WiFi and bluetooth radios are examples of standardized packet radios that work in the 2.4GHz unlicensed band.

It is not difficult to find [similar devices in the 902MHz band](http://www.digi.com/technology/wireless/products.jsp), including standardized [ZigBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee) mesh radio equipment.

Licensed [amateur radio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio) operators enjoy some advantages the unlicensed devices cannot provide, such as higher power limits and more diverse frequency choices.  But these privileges come with restrictions - for example autonomous operation is not permitted in the "shortwave" bands, and operation for any commercial purpose is prohibited.

As Adam mentioned, The [APRS standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Packet_Reporting_System) is a de-facto standard for the format of informational beacons and the method for repeating them across the amateur packet radio network.

From your post I feel that you want "wide-area" service that you can track a roaming device with.  Although many areas have existing APRS ["digipeaters"](http://wa8lmf.net/DigiPaths/) setup by local hams, they are all voluntary as the bands can't be used for commercial purposes.  As a licensed operator, you could of course setup your own repeaters.

Many types of communications are prohibited on the Amateur Radio bands, but this leaves plenty of room for hobbyist and personal research efforts, and as an Extra class ham I would welcome your project!

Answer (score 2):

The search term you want to use is "APRS" - Automatic packet reporting system.  Many people and companies already have GPS to radio interfaces that work with the HAM APRS system so you can track vehicles and other objects (such as balloons) through this HAM radio network.

Answer (score 0):

The gps will probably have a serial connection prinitng out the position as a standard NMEA string.

There are a few protocols for sending RS-232 Ascii over ham radio - start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_radio)

Answer (score 0):

Amateur radio is not really free - there are obviously no carrier fees, but you need a license to transmit and approved equipment. It's not a free-for-all.

Comment: Since the Amateur Radio Service allows self-built or -modified equipment, it doesn't have to be "approved", but it's still illegal to make noncompliant transmissions.  It's your responsibility as a licensed operator to make sure what comes out of the radio is compliant.